# ¿Cómo puedo subir un archivo completo al repositorio de GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

¿Cómo puedo subir un archivo completo al repositorio de GitLab? Ya tengo el proyecto listo, ¿cómo subo la carpeta entera? Gracias.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/ funciona igual que gitlab

Answer (score 1):

Crea un repositorio local en Git primero, aquí puedes añadir toda la carpeta sin problema. Tras ello crea un repositorio remoto en GitLab y añadelo a tu repositorio loca.

Luego haz un Commit haciendo StagedAll en el repositorio local. Para acabar haz Push en el repositorio local y se te subiran todos los archivos a GitLab automaticamente.

Todo ello te será más fácil si usa alguna herramienta como SourceTree de Atlassian o uno similar para utilizar Git en tu PC, ya que tiene una interfaz muy sencilla y autoexplicativa.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: excelente muchas gracias !